# Narrowing conversation from int to signed char, но никакого преобразования нет

Tags: c++

Написал такую функцию:

```cpp
char getDigitInRadix(char d, int radix) {
    if (d < 10)
        return d + (char)48;
    // дальнейший код
}
```

`Clion` подсвечивает `d` и выдаёт предупреждение: `Clang-Tidy: Narrowing conversion from 'int' to signed type 'char' is implementation-defined`, хотя никакого преобразования тут нет: `d` имеет тип `char`, он складывается с выражением типа `char`, функция в результате возвращает выражение типа `char`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По неизвестным причинам С++ не поддерживает арифметические операции для целочисленных типов меньше `int`. В выражении `return d + (char)48;` каждый операнд сначала преобразуется в `int`, а затем результирующий `int` преобразуется в `char`.